# How to calculate the group by count of keys in a dictionary?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dim idQueuedJobs As IDictionary(Of Int32, KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)) = New Dictionary(Of Int32, KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32))
```

Why duplicate KeyValue pair? This is because the first **Int32** is just a normal index, and the **String** followed by another **Int32** contains systemnames and the priority of the qued job in *idQueuedJobs*

I want to calculate the total number of systemnames in *idQueuedJobs*, how can i obtain this count by using the groupby method?

Something like this maybe?

```
numberOfSystems As Int32 = idQueuedJobs.Values.GroupBy(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
idQueuedJobs.Add(1, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM1", 1))
idQueuedJobs.Add(2, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM1", 2))
idQueuedJobs.Add(3, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM1", 1))
idQueuedJobs.Add(4, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM1", 3))
idQueuedJobs.Add(5, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM1", 4))
idQueuedJobs.Add(6, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM2", 1))
idQueuedJobs.Add(7, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM2", 2))
idQueuedJobs.Add(8, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM3", 3))
idQueuedJobs.Add(9, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM3", 3))
idQueuedJobs.Add(10, New KeyValuePair(Of String, Int32)("SYSTEM3", 4))

Dim numberOfSystems As Int32 = idQueuedJobs.Values.GroupBy(Of String)(Function(p) p.Key).Count
```

The following code will result in *numberOfSystems* = 3

Comment: Does the GroupBy need to have GroupBy(Of String)?